# ValueError when running Python function in data pipeline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, data-pipeline

I'm building a data pipeline using Python and I'm running into an issue when trying to execute a certain function. The error message I'm receiving is: `ValueError: Could not convert string to float: 'N/A'`

Here is the function in question:

```
def process_data(data):
    for item in data:
        # Do some processing...
        value = float(item[1])
        if value > 0:
            processed_item = process_item(item)
            yield processed_item
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
data = [('A', '1.5'), ('B', '2.7'), ('C', 'N/A'), ('D', '4.1'), ('E', '5.9')]
processed_data = process_data(data)
```

**Code:**

```
def process_data(data):
    for item in data:
        # Do some processing...
        value = float(item[1])
        if value > 0:
            processed_item = process_item(item)
            yield processed_item

data = [('A', '1.5'), ('B', '2.7'), ('C', 'N/A'), ('D', '4.1'), ('E', '5.9')]
processed_data = process_data(data)
```

**Error message:**

```
ValueError: Could not convert string to float: 'N/A'
```

The expected outcome was to process the items in the data list and yield the processed items if the value of the item was greater than 0.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in this case? A string like this does not represent a number. You need to manually handle this special case in a way that is suitable for your task. For some general information how to catch them you can lookup try..catch and type conversions.

Comment: Can you please specify what your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter value of `float(parameter)` must be a number or a string that can be converted into a floating point number.

The value ***'N/A'*** cannot be converted because it is not a **number**.

You could try:

```
try:
    value = float(item[1])
except ValueError:
    value = 0
```

Assuming you want anything that is not a number to become zero, which will then be filtered out by your `if value > 0:` statement.

Comment: Note that `float("nan")` is valid, and won't raise a `ValueError`